# JQuery AJAX $.post failure to return data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having difficulty with a specific JQuery $.post call to a PHP-based processor. I created a test page with the code below located here: http://goo.gl/Bg7H2u

Note this is located on a subdomain, but we are not doing cross-domain posting. Everything should be included on the subdomain.

There do not seem to be any JS errors as reported in the error console.

The processor /get-data.html is the general purpose PHP processor, and, if you load the processor page with the right value, it returns a dataset from the MySQL database in JSON format. We have this working on the main domain without issue, and other $.post calls seem to work OK from this subdomain (not to this /get-data.html processor, but other processors that process form content).

See the actual processor output here: http://goo.gl/yOzrm2

I must be missing something obvious, but I am coming up empty. Thoughts?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320px, initial-scale=1">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var prices;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post( "/get-data.html", { table: 'prices' }, 
        function( data ) { 
            prices = data;
            alert(prices);
        }, 'json');
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="overflow-x: hidden;" id="divMain">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Comment: And what is the result of `alert`?

Comment: Your server side script doesn't return JSON notation object

Comment: Agreed with @A.Wolff, it's even wrapped in `<p>`. Do you expect it to be json? Really?

Comment: Your server is returning JSON inside a `<p>` element.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the JS console?

Comment: @Barmar There are no errors in the console. Seems that jQuery just fails silently when it fails to parse the response as JSON.

Comment: @JLRishe From `$.post` DOC: `If a request with jQuery.post() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError() method. Alternatively, as of jQuery 1.5, the .error() method of the jqXHR object returned by jQuery.post() is also available for error handling.`  So indeed, error should be explecitely handled, using e.g: `$.post(...).fail(handler);`

Comment: @A.Wolff Ah, should've read the docs a bit more closely.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's a side effect of the CMS--it adds <p> tags. I should've thought to check it. Thanks again.

Comment: @u_mulder I knew it would be something simple I was overlooking, hence asking for assistance to get another pair of eyes. Really no reason to be rude about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `View Source` on the processor output, you'll see that your script is returning:

```
<p>{"Basic Plan":["349"],"Basic":["349"],"Premium Plan":["549"],"Premium":["549"],"Standard Plan":["429"],"Standard":["429"],"Bonus Plan":["175"],"Additional Central AC System":["99"],"Additional central heating system":["99"],"Central Vacuum":["99"],"Whole home humidifier":["49"],"Pool (in-ground)":["179"],"Spa (in-ground)":["179"],"Septic System":["99"],"Sump Pump":["99"],"Well pump":["99"],"Whole home water softener":["99"],"Lawn sprinkler system (in-ground)":["99"],"Wine refrigerator":["49"],"Ice maker (free standing)":["49"],"Home phone (unlimited)":["49"],"TV Protection (Flat screen up to 60 inches)":["99"],"PC Protection (laptop or desktop)":["49"]}</p>
```

There's `<p>` at the beginning and `</p>` at the end. This is not valid JSON. You need to fix the server script so that it doesn't print anything other than the JSON (whitespace is OK, that's it).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that would be the issue. The CMS editor adds <p> tags and I didn't realize it was doing so. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

1.confirm that /get-data.html is the correct relational url for your file location.

2. If you navigate directly to the /get-data.html, does it produce the results that you are after.
3. try running the same code without , 'json' and see if it works.

hope this helps